# Написать функцию capitalize. Функция должна возвращать новую строку, в которой каждое слово начинается с прописной буквы

Tags: javascript, if, map

Помогите решить задачу и верно написать изменения

```
function capitalize(str) {
  if (typeof(str) !== 'str'){
   
    return ("нет данных");
} else return (
    str.split(' ').arr.map().slice(1).join(' ')
)
}

capitalize('Надоел, надоел, надоел ты'); // Надоел, Надоел, Надоел Ты
capitalize('Надоели, надоели, надоели вы все'); // Надоели, Надоели, Надоели Вы Все
```

Comment: давно отвечено: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1026087/14256576

Answer (score 0):

```
function capitalize(str) {
  if (typeof str !== 'string'){
    return "нет данных";
  }
  
  return str.split(" ").map(word => {
          return `${word[0].toUpperCase()}${word.slice(1, word.length)}`;
     }).join(" ");
}

capitalize('Надоел, надоел, надоел ты'); // Надоел, Надоел, Надоел Ты
capitalize('Надоели, надоели, надоели вы все'); // Надоели, Надоели, Надоели Вы Все
```